# Retrieving return code from child process using wait()?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child

I have 2 files "prime.c" and "singlePrime.c" and inside of singlePrime.c I am trying to create a child that morphs itself into "isPrime.exe" which is an executable made out of "prime.c". What I want to do is get the return number from isPrime.exe so either 1 or 0 depending on if the input number is prime or not and then store it in childNum inside of the main() function of "singlePrime.c" so that I can print to the terminal whether it's a prime number or not based on 1 or 0 that is returned from "isPrime.exe". Below are my 2 files:

prime.c:

```
/*
File is isPrime.c

Purpose:
a program that checks if a given number is a prime number

input:
number - a positive int  entered via the command line parameters.  For example isPrime 1234

output:
0 - if the input number is not a prime number
1 - if the input number is a prime number
2 - if the command line parameter is not correct

Assumption:
the program does not check if the number is a positive integer

*/


#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include "prime.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;

        int number;

        if (argc < 2) {
            printf("Returning 2");
            return(2);
        }
        else number = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (isPrime(number)) {
                exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);
}


/*
Purpose: check if the input number is a prime number
input:
number - the number to be checked

return:
0 - if the number is not a prime number
1 - if the number is a prime number
*/
int isPrime(int number)
{
        int i;
        for(i = 2; i*i < number; i++) {
                usleep(100);
                if (number % i == 0) {
                        printf("%d is not a prime number!",number);
                        return(0);
                }
        }
        printf("%d is a prime number!",number);
        return(1);
}
```

singlePrime.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include "prime.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int number, childNum;

        if (!atoi(argv[1])) {
                printf("Please use a valid integer as an argument!");
                exit(1);
        }

        int pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
                wait(childNum);
                morph(argv[1]);
        }

        else {
                if (childNum == 0) {
                        printf("The input number is not a prime number!");
                        exit(1);
                }
                else if (childNum == 1) {
                        printf("The input number is a prime number!");
                        exit(1);
                }
                else if (childNum == 2) {
                        printf("Please input a number greater than 2!");
                        exit(1);
                }
        }
}

void morph(char *number)
{
        char *primeArgv[] = {
                "isPrime.exe",
                number,
                NULL,
        };

        execvp("isPrime.exe",primeArgv);               
}
```

Comment: You should use threading, either posix threads or windows own threading API. That way you can simply fork threads (create background child processes) and keep everything in the same executable. It's much simpler than having multiple programs.

Comment: we are told we have to use the wait() function

Comment: you can call wait() from within any forked thread

Comment: as I stated in another answer, this algorithm to determine if a number is prime fails for the number 4

Comment: regarding this code block: 'if (isPrime(number)) {  exit(1)  }  exit(0);'  it would be much clearer and simpler to use: '' return( isPrime(number) );"

Comment: due to stdout buffering, the calls to printf() first parameter should end in '\n' so the stdout buffer will be flushed in a timely manner

Comment: please read the man page for each system function being used, so coding errors, such as the 'wait()' statement being passed a int rather than a pointer to an int can be avoided.  perform all compiles with all warnings enabled, so the compiler can inform you of problems that need correction

Answer (score 2):

For starters, this

```
wait(childNum);
```

should have made the compiler issue a clear warning, from which you could have drawn that there is something wrong.

And indeed you are using `wait()` wrongly. It expects a pointer:

```
wait(int * status);
```

Use it in the following way:

```
  {
    int status;
    int result;

    do
    {
      result = 0;
      if ((pid_t) -1) == wait(&status)))
      {
        result = -1;
        if (errno == EINTR)
        {
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          perror("wait() failed");
        }
      }

      break;
    } while (1);

    if (-1 != result)
    {
      if (WIFEXITED(status))
      {
        int ec = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("The child's exit code is %d\n", ec);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("The child did not provide an exit code. It probably crashed?\n");
      }
    }
  }
```

Details can be read in [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html).

---

Also this code somehow does not make sense:

```
        if (pid == 0) {
            wait(childNum);
            morph(argv[1]);
        }
```

You are calling `wait()` from the child, and only after it returned you `exec*` `isPrime.exe`.

You may want to do it like this

```
      pid = fork();
      if (-1 == pid)
      {
         perror("fork() failed");
      }
      else if (pid == 0) 
      {
        morph(argv[1]);
      }
      else
      {
        /* wait code as shown above goes here.
           childNum needs to get assigend. */
        if (childNum == 0) {
        ....
      }
```

---

Also^2 the code does not test whether the call to `execvp()` succeeded.

Put a `perror("execvp() failed");` right after the it.

---

Also^3 this

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
```

should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Does this get the the exit number or the return number? If it gets the exit number should I change the returns in "prime.c" to exit(0) instead of return 0 etc?

Comment: @user3373360: Calling `exit(0)` somewhere is equivalent to `return 0` from `main()`.

Comment: okay but now I am getting the child's exit code is 255. I want to be getting either 1 or 0 so I can detect if the number is prime or not?

Comment: I applied these changes but I am still getting that the exit code is 255. I feel like we're very close to the solution here though

Comment: okay now it's working but it says that execvp() failed: No such file or directory. So the way I am using it must be wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74294/discussion-between-user3373360-and-alk).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly use fork(), check the system() function (http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), which gives you nice and easy the return code of the other process.

Comment: We are told we have to use the wait() function though