# true story of return statement in linux processes

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system

I am trying to configure the output for this simple code. But i am unable to understand.
expected output is

```
int main() 
{ 
     int val = 5; 
     if(fork()) 
         wait(&val); 
     val++; 
     printf("%d\n", val); 
     return val; 
}
```

expected output is

```
6
7
```

but linux is giving me

```
6
1537
```

kindly can anyone tell me what is happening behind this code.
i can predict that there must be something wrong with return statement.
detailed explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Reading [the manual page of `wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) will help you understand. Short story even shorter: The actual return code is only in the eight lowest bits.

Comment: Why didn't you expect 6/7?

Comment: The "*lowest*"? 1537 is 0x601. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @alk From the linked manual page, regarding the `WEXITSTATUS` macro: "returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the **least significant 8 bits** of the status argument..." (emphasis mine).

Comment: It seems that your answers are more detailed than me about the return value. Anyone knows exactly what's happening with the value ? Why it's 1537 ?

Comment: Ahok, I misunderstood you in terms to which value you were refering to to take the 8 LSB from. @JoachimPileborg I though you were referring to the value `wait()` would write to where its parameters points to.

Comment: See the first part of this answer on how to get a process' return code via a call to `wait()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29397686/694576

Comment: i am astonished that why and through which algorithm it is returning 1537 ?

Comment: fork(), when it fails, returns -1.  the 'if will evaluate 'true' when fork() returns -1  Suggest: pid_t pid = fork();  if (0 > pid) { handle error  and exit } if (!pid) { handle child }  else {handle parent{

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is to change the parameter value of the function **wait()**.

```
int main() 
{ 
     int val = 5; 
     if(fork()) 
         wait(NULL); 
     val++; 
     printf("%d\n", val); 
     return val; 
}
```

Your output was **1537** because the status() function change your variable value.

Extract of the man of **wait()** where **status** represents the parameter of the function.

> If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points.

Good luck.

Comment: more needs to be changed in this code than just the 'wait' statement.  this is because fork() can fail, returning -1, which would satisfy the 'if' statement  then the parent would be waiting on a non existent child